# Can I fill NaN-Values of one column with specific list elements of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have following dataframe (called items) for example:

```
| index | itemID | maintopic | subtopics          |
|:----- |:------:|:---------:| ------------------:|
| 1     | 235    | FBR       | [FZ, 1RH, FL]      |
| 2     | 1787   | NaN       | [1RH, YRS, FZ, FL] |
| 3     | 2454   | NaN       | [FZX, 1RH, FZL]    |
| 4     | 3165   | NaN       | [YHS]              |
```

I would like to fill the NaN-Values in the maintopic-column with the first element of the subtopics list which starts with a letter. Does someone has an idea? (Question No 1)

I tried this, but it didn´t work:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    
items['maintopic'] = items['maintopic'].apply(lambda x : items['maintopic'].fillna(items['subtopics'][x][0]) if items['subtopics'][x][0].lower().startswith(tuple(alphabet)) else x)
```

Advanced (Question No 2):
Even better would be to have a look at all elements of the subtopics list and if there are more elements which have the first letter or even the first and the second letter in common, then I would like to take this. For example in line 2 there is FZ and FL, so i would like to fill the maintopic in this row with an F. And in line 3 there is FZX and FZL, then I would like to fill the maintopic with FZ. But if this is way too complicated then I would be also very happy with an answer to Question No 1.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations


def commonprefix(m):
    "Given a list of pathnames, returns the longest common leading component"
    if not m:
        return ""
    s1 = min(m)
    s2 = max(m)
    for i, c in enumerate(s1):
        if c != s2[i]:
            return s1[:i]
    return s1


def powerset(iterable, n=0):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(n, len(s) + 1))


def choose(x):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        return x

    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0]

    filtered = [v for v in x if not v[0].isdigit()]
    if not filtered:
        return np.nan

    longest = ""
    for s in powerset(filtered, 2):
        pref = commonprefix(s)
        if len(pref) > len(longest):
            longest = pref

    return filtered[0] if longest == "" else longest


m = df["maintopic"].isna()
df.loc[m, "maintopic"] = df.loc[m, "subtopics"].apply(choose)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   index  itemID maintopic           subtopics
0      1     235       FBR       [FZ, 1RH, FL]
1      2    1787         F  [1RH, YRS, FZ, FL]
2      3    2454        FZ     [FZX, 1RH, FZL]
3      4    3165       YHS               [YHS]
```

EDIT: Added checks for a list/float.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, I appreciate it!
Unfortunately it gives me an error back if I use it on my whole dataframe:
"TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". Do you have an idea what the problem could be in my dataframe?

Comment: @leolumpy Which line gives you the error? Is every row in "subtopics" a list? Is every element in this list a string?

Comment: This line here: items.loc[m, "maintopic"] = items.loc[m, "subtopics"].apply(choose)

Actually yes, but I am not for 100 % sure. The dataframe is really big with 78000 rows. Can I check it somehow?

Comment: @leolumpy Can you paste the full stack trace? That't only the highest level of it.

Comment: I am trying, but the formatting is really bad. Sorry for that, I am pretty new, it´s my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: ---> 39 items.loc[m, "maintopic"] = items.loc[m, "subtopics"].apply(choose)

-> 4135                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

---> 23     filtered = [v for v in x if not v[0].isdigit()]

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

The whole stack is unfortunately too long ...

Comment: @leolumpy I updated my code. Added some checks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231689/discussion-between-leolumpy-and-andrej-kesely).

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the first question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def fill_value(sub):
    for i in sub:
        if i[0].isalpha():
            return i
    return sub[0]


data = {
    'maintopic': ['FBR', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'subtopic': [['FZ', '1RH', 'FL'] , ['1RH', 'YRS', 'FZ', 'FL'], ['FZX', '1RH', 'FZL'], ['YHS']]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print('Before\n', df)
df['maintopic'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: fill_value(row['subtopic']) if pd.isnull(row['maintopic']) else row['maintopic'],
    axis=1
)
print('\nAfter\n', df)
```

Output:

```
Before
   maintopic            subtopic
0       FBR       [FZ, 1RH, FL]
1       NaN  [1RH, YRS, FZ, FL]
2       NaN     [FZX, 1RH, FZL]
3       NaN               [YHS]

After
   maintopic            subtopic
0       FBR       [FZ, 1RH, FL]
1       YRS  [1RH, YRS, FZ, FL]
2       FZX     [FZX, 1RH, FZL]
3       YHS               [YHS]
```

You can change the fill_value function to return the desired values to fill NaN values. For now, I have returned the first value of the subtopic that starts with an alphabet.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! Your solution looks very nice and if I copy paste, then it works absolutely fine! But if I use it on my whole dataframe, it says "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". :( Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this : get all substrings that start with first letter in each value in the list of `subtopics` columns and build a counter and then sort the items in the counter based on their frequency. If the items' frequency is same consider the longest string.

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import cmp_to_key
def get_main_topic_modified(m, l):
    if m is not np.nan:
       return m
    if len(l) == 1:
       return l[0]
    res = []
    for s in l:
        il = [s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s)-1)]
        res.append(il)
    res = [item for s in res for item in s]
    c = Counter(res)
    d = dict(c)
    l = list(d.items())
    
    l.sort(key=cmp_to_key(lambda x, y: len(y[0])-len(x[0]) if x[1] == y[1] else y[1] - x[1]))
    
    return l[0][0]

df['maintopic'] = df[['maintopic', 'subtopics']].apply(
                       lambda x : get_main_topic_modified(*x), axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
  index itemID  maintopic            subtopics
0     1    235        FBR        [FZ, 1RH, FL]
1     2   1787          F   [1RH, YRS, FZ, FL]
2     3   2454         FZ      [FZX, 1RH, FZL]
3     4   3165        YHS                [YHS]
```